# Tkinter: use root.after() properly

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to create a projectile that every second move 10 pixel along his y axis
using the after() function.
The first attempt I've done is this:

```
  def muovi(self, root):
    i = 0
    while i < 10:
        i += 1
        self.parent.move(self.colpo, 0, 10)
        root.after(1000)
```

The problem is that it completely ignore *self.parent.move(self.colpo, 0, 10)*
, which only works at the end of the loop.
Then I tried with this:

```
    def muovi(self, root):
        self.parent.move(self.colpo, 0, 10)
        root.after(1000, self.muovi(root))
```

This time the code run like if instead of *root.after(1000, self.muovi(root))* there is *self.muovi(root))*, so I get *Recursion Error* instantly.

How can let *root.after()* work properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code:

```
root.after(1000, self.muovi(root))
```

is functionally identical to this code:

```
result = self.muovi(root)
root.after(1000, result)
```

Do you see the problem? You are *calling* `self.muovi` and giving the result to `after`. Instead, you must supply a *reference* to `self.muovi`. Additional positional arguments can be used as arguments following the reference:

```
root.after(1000, self.muovi, root)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first piece of code does not work because you haven't specified the function that will be called after 1000 ms.

And your second piece of code does not work because the second argument expected by `after` is a function, like for the `command` option of a button.

Here is an example:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Button

def move():
    canvas.move(circle, 0, 10)
    root.after(1000, move) # the second argument as to be a function, not move()

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
circle = canvas.create_oval(10,10,30,30, fill='red')

Button(root, text="Start", command=move).pack()

root.mainloop()
```