# Recursion error using tkinter root.after

Tags: python, tkinter, while-loop, window, root

I'm making a tkinter program in which it will be needed to make the connection with Arduino via serial (but that's not very important).

Before explaining my problem, here is the code:

```
def arduino_makeConnection():

    global arduino

    try:
        arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600, timeout = 0)

    except:
        print "Failed to connect"
        if(time.time()-time_start<20):             
            root.after(0,arduino_makeConnection())



global time_start
time_start=time.time()
arduino_makeConnection()
```

So, I want to try to make connection via serial with the arduino only during 20s. After that time, I want it to give it up.

The problem is that my tkinter window doesn't open even though it prints in my console "Failed to connect" many many times until it gets the message (way before the 20 seconds have run off): **RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp**

I have tried to change time from 0 to 10 or 100ms on the root.after, but that doesn't solve the problem.

I think this has something to do with event handler, or something like that. However I thought that as I am not using a **While** or any other kind of loop, Tkinter would work...

Actually, before using the **root.after** I was making a **While** that was only breaking after the 20s or insead if the arduino was plugged in during that time. However when I searched in the internet, I realized that a loop in Tkinter is not a good idea. So, I changed to the root.after method, but now it's not working either!

Any help?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @DYZ The OP did write a loop, and `root.after` usually *is* the proper way with tkinter.  The problem is recursively calling the callback in the callback.  The solution is to pass the callback without calling it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tkinter: use root.after() properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41661396/tkinter-use-root-after-properly) See the second `def muovi:` and the first, accepted, answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
root.after(0,arduino_makeConnection())
```

This is exactly the same as this code:

```
result = arduino_makeConnection()
root.after(0, result)
```

And, assuming your function doesn't return anything, it's exactly the same as this:

```
root.after(0, None)
```

See the problem? The `after` command must be given a reference to a callable. In short, remove the parenthesis:

```
root.after(0,arduino_makeConnection)
```

Also, I *highly* recommend against using 0 (zero) as the first parameter. At the very least you should use 1 (one). A value of zero can have surprising side effects because you essentially create an infinite event queue that never empties.

Comment: As I understand, callin a function with the ()'s, actually "calls" for the value that the function returns. On the other hand, calling without the ()'s, actually calls the function object. I just can't understand the difference!! I mean, by removing the ()'s, "calling callback() calls callback() calls ... " is no longer happening?

Comment: @ajcoelho: Using parenthesis calls a function. Without the parenthesis the function is _not_ called. Instead, you are simply telling `after` which funtion to run in the future.

Comment: Okay! That makes sense!! Sorry, perhaps I did not understand this at first because my function doesn't actually return a thing. It's like a void function I'd say... Anyway I should have realized this faster because this is exactly what I do when creating buttons!

Answer (score 1):

If you tried to make an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you might come up with

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

def callback():
    print('callback')
    root.after(0, callback())
callback()
```

This might make it more obvious that calling callback() calls callback() calls ..., until you get the recursion error.  Remove the `()` in the `root.after` call.  Also use a non-zero delay.  Try the above with, for instance, `root.after(100, callback).

Comment: It worked! I've made a little search: as I understand, callin a function with the ()'s, actually "calls" for the value that the function returns. On the other hand, calling without the ()'s, actually calls the function object. I just can't understand the difference!! I mean, by removing the ()'s, "calling callback() calls callback() calls ... " is no longer happening?

Comment: Without the ()s, the function is not called.  Instead, the *function object* is passed to after() to be called *later*.  The value of the expression `int` is the int function.  The value of the expression `int()` is int 0 (the default return of the int function.