# Tkinter freezing every time causing Python to not respond

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to use tkinter for a basic popup window that lets you start and stop recording data. However, every time I run it, the window freezes and I get "Python is not responding".

I've googled it and found that using sleep() is a common cause but as I am not using that in my code, I am unsure as to what the problem could be.

```
import serial 
import numpy as np 
import msvcrt as m
import time
import os
from tkinter import * 

moment = time.strftime("%Y-%b-%d_%H%M%S",time.localtime())

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        sd = "Data"
        try:
            os.mkdir(sd)
        except Exception:
            pass
        global f
        f= open(os.path.join(sd, "data"+ moment +".txt"),"w+")
        self.f = f
        super(Application,self).__init__(master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()
        self._alarm_id = None
        self._paused = False

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.someFrame = Frame(self)
        self.startButton = Button(self.someFrame, text="Start     Recording",command=self.startRecord)
        self.startButton.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.stopButton = Button(self.someFrame, text="Stop Recording", command=self.stopRecord)
        self.stopButton.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.resetButton = Button(self.someFrame, text="Reset", command=self.resetRecord)
        self.resetButton.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.someFrame.pack(side=TOP)

        self.labelvariable = StringVar()
        self.labelvariable.set("Waiting")

        self.thelabel = Label(self,textvariable = self.labelvariable,font=('Helvetica',50))
        self.thelabel.pack(side=TOP)

    def startRecord(self):
        """ Start/Resume """
        self._paused = False
        app.labelvariable.set("Recording")
        if self._alarm_id is None:
            self.record()

    def stopRecord(self):
        """ Stop/Pause """
        app.labelvariable.set("Paused")
        if self._alarm_id is not None:
            self._paused = True

    def resetRecord(self):
        """ Resets and creates new file"""
        app.labelvariable.set("Cleared")
        f = self.f
        f.close()
        sd = "Data"
        try:
            os.mkdir(sd)
        except Exception:
            pass
        moment = time.strftime("%Y-%b-%d_%H%M%S",time.localtime())
        f= open(os.path.join(sd, "data"+ moment +".txt"),"w+")
        if self._alarm_id is not None:
            self.master.after_cancel(self._alarm_id)
            self._alarm_id = None
            self._paused = False
            self.record()
            self._paused = True

    def record(self, start=True):
        if start:
            arduinoData = serial.Serial('com3', 9600)
            while self._paused is False:
                while (arduinoData.inWaiting()==0): 
                    pass
                arduinoString = arduinoData.readline() 
                vlt = float(arduinoString)   
                f.write("%d\r\n" %(vlt))
        if self._paused:
            self._alarm_id = self.master.after(1000, self.record, False)
        else:
            app.labelvariable.set("")
            self._alarm_id = self.master.after(1000, self.record, False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.title("EMG")
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It's almost certainly something to do with `while self._paused is False:`.

Comment: While that `while` loop is executing, those five lines inside it are *the only things your program is doing*.  None of those lines can possibly change the value of `self._paused`, therefore the loop is infinite.  You seem to understand how `.after()` works, you need to do the same thing (on a much shorter time scale) to read the lines of incoming data, without blocking the execution of the overall program.  (Or do the reading in a separate thread or process, possibly.)

Answer (score 0):

don't use `while` statement!

use this: `root.after()`: [how to use root.after()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41661396/tkinter-use-root-after-properly)

Comment: I changed it so I have `callback = root.after(1, self.writeData)` and then `root.after_cancel(callback)` to stop it but now it's giving me an error saying that it cannot convert a string to a float.